# How to write a simple, unwrapped, byte array to an Apache-Arrow ListWriter

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I'm currently writing some code to convert an arbitrary data structure to Apache Arrow vectors and got stuck on something relatively simple, namely, how to write a `byte[]` to a `ListVector`.

When writing data to a `ListVector` through a `BaseWriter.ListWriter`, primitive types can be added very easily – ie, `writer.integer().writeInt(i)` or `writer.float4().writeFloat4(f)`.

However, for variable length types like bytes (or strings), one is only left with methods with signatures similar to:

```
public void write(VarBinaryHolder h);

public void writeVarBinary(int start, int end, ArrowBuf buffer);
```

<sub>With `VarBinaryHolder` being a simple generated wrapper class for an `ArrowBuf` that does not even have a constructor.</sub>

I was expecting something similar to what the `VarBinaryVector` offers, which has a `Mutator` with a `setSafe(int index, byte[] bytes)` method that does exactly what is expected.

Furthermore, there seems to be no straightforward way to wrap a byte array into an `ArrowBuf`, the only one I see being to write data to a fresh `VarBinaryVector` and fetching the underlying `ArrowBuf` afterwards.

So, my interrogations are:

- Is it just the API missing a method, or should I not even be using a list vector to store lists of bytes<sup>1</sup>?
- Is there another obvious way to do this that I missed?

---

<sup>1</sup>  A `VarBinaryVector` would do for simple cases, but I want to be able to nest lists as well. Also, the list's ability to contain multiple types can be useful as well.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I probably found a workaround back then (would not be able to remember, though >.>)